# I am working on my kick command and I came up with this erorr:

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Hello I am working on my kick command and I came up with this error:

```
(node:2559) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number.
    at Function.resolve (/rbd/pnpm-volume/cad5e42d-dfa3-46df-b985-a6e43aa649d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:150:19)
    at Permissions.has (/rbd/pnpm-volume/cad5e42d-dfa3-46df-b985-a6e43aa649d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:45:28)
    at Permissions.has (/rbd/pnpm-volume/cad5e42d-dfa3-46df-b985-a6e43aa649d2/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Permissions.js:45:85)
```

I want to make a mute role for my mute command here is my command:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  //console.log(message.member)
  const permissions = message.channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
  let perm=message.channel.permissionsFor(message.member)//perm.has()
  if(!permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.noMentionReply(`${process.env.EMOTE_NO || '<:tairitsuno:869919370208509962>'}`+" | I don't have permission to kick!!!");
 if (!perm.has("KICK_MEMBERS")&&!perm.has("MANAGE_GUILD")&&!perm.has("MANAGE_MEMBERS")&&!perm.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
        return message.mentionReply(`${process.env.EMOTE_NO || '<:tairitsuno:869919370208509962>'}`+" | You don't have permission to kick!!!");

 if (!args[0]) {
        return message.mentinReply(
          `${process.env.EMOTE_NO || '<:tairitsuno:869919370208509962>'}`+" |Please mention or give the id of the person who you want to kick"
        );
      }
      let target = await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0].replace("<@!", "").replace("<@","").replace(">","")).catch(err => { return message.mentionReply(`${process.env.EMOTE_NO || '<:tairitsuno:869919370208509962>'}`+" | Unable to find this Person") });

      if (target === !args[0]) {
        return message.mentionReply(
          `${process.env.EMOTE_NO || '<:tairitsuno:869919370208509962>'}`+" | Please mention or give the id of the person who you want to kick"
        );
      }
      
      if (target.id === message.author.id) {
        return message.mentionReply(`${process.env.EMOTE_NO || '<:tairitsuno:869919370208509962>'}`+" | You can not kick yourself");
      }
  let tar=message.channel.permissionsFor(target)//perm.has()
      if (tar.has("ADMINISTRATOR")){
        return message.mentionReply(`${process.env.EMOTE_NO || '<:tairitsuno:869919370208509962>'}`+" | The user you want to kick is a moderator/administrator I can't do that,try to kick him/her/them yourself..");
  }
  let BotRole = message.guild.member(message.guild.me).roles.highest.position;

    let Role = target.roles.highest.position;

    let UserRole = message.member.roles.highest.position;

    if (UserRole <= Role) return message.mentionReply(`${process.env.EMOTE_NO || '<:tairitsuno:869919370208509962>'}`+' | You can\'t kick that user because that user has a role position which is higher than yours, or has a same role position as you!');
      let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
      if (!reason) reason = "-";
      message.noMentionReply("kicking...")
      .then(msg => {
        let reasonb = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        target.kick({reason: reason+` || by ${message.member.user.tag}`});
        if(!reasonb){
        msg.edit(`${process.env.EMOTE_OK || '<:hikariok:869920204786925608>'} | Kicked sucessfully`)
        };
      if(reasonb) {
        msg.edit(`${process.env.EMOTE_OK || '<:hikariok:869920204786925608>'} | Kicked sucessfully **|** ${reason}`);}
    });
      
}


exports.info = {
  name: 'kick',
  aliases:[],
  usage: "<user_id_or_mention>",
  description: "kicks a member"
}//checked
exports.conf={
  cooldown: 0,
  dm: "no"
}
```

I don't quite know how to fix it please help me

Comment: See this link for all valid permission flags - note that `MANAGE_MEMBERS` isn't one of them. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) for all valid permission flags - note that `MANAGE_MEMBERS` isn't one of them.

Comment: The ones related to member management: `BAN_MEMBERS`, `KICK_MEMBERS`, `MANAGE_ROLES`, `MANAGE_NICKNAMES`, `MUTE_MEMBERS`, `DEAFEN_MEMBERS`, `MOVE_MEMBERS`

Comment: Thx youuuuuu xD